# Quarkus JAX-RS Service Multipart Form Upload - "Cannot consume content type"

Tags: rest, file-upload, jax-rs, multipartform-data, quarkus

I'm writing a JAX-RS service using Quarkus.  My service should create a simple user profile with name, date of birth, etc. along with an upload image file.  I'm trying to do this as a multipart form upload, but keep running into errors.

My service definition looks something like this...

```
@Path("/profile")
@POST
@Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response createStudentProfile(@MultipartForm ProfileFormBean profile);
```

My `ProfileFormBean` class looks like this...

```
public class ProfileFormBean {

    @FormParam("firstName")
    @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    private String firstName = null;

    @FormParam("lastName")
    @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    private String lastName = null;

    @FormParam("profileImage")
    @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    private byte[] profileImage = null;

    ...
}
```

As best I can tell, this should be enough for my service to accept file uploads.  I'm trying to test this out using curl, but when I do so I get an exception.  My curl command is just trying to upload the file itself, not setting the first/last name properties:

```sh
curl -vki -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
    -H 'Accepts: application/json' \
    -F 'profileImage=@profile_image.jpg' \
    http://localhost:8081/profile
```

The output to this command looks like this:

```sh
curl -vki -H "Authorization: Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
> -H 'Accepts: application/json' \
> -F 'profileImage=@profile_image.jpg' \
> http://localhost:8081/profile
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8081 (#0)
> POST /profile HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8081
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1N...
> Accepts: application/json
> Content-Length: 11701
> Expect: 100-continue
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------49161ebc82f19511
> 
< HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
< Content-Length: 0
Content-Length: 0

* HTTP error before end of send, stop sending
< 
* Closing connection 0
```

And on the server when I run this I see the following Exception:

```
15:26:35 DEBUG [org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy_jaxrs.i18n] RESTEASY002305: Failed executing POST /profile: javax.ws.rs.NotSupportedException: RESTEASY003065: Cannot consume content type
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:453)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.SegmentNode.match(SegmentNode.java:155)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootNode.match(RootNode.java:58)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.registry.RootClassNode.match(RootClassNode.java:47)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodRegistry.getResourceInvoker(ResourceMethodRegistry.java:482)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getInvoker(SynchronousDispatcher.java:323)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$invoke$4(SynchronousDispatcher.java:244)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.lambda$preprocess$0(SynchronousDispatcher.java:153)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.interception.jaxrs.PreMatchContainerRequestContext.filter(PreMatchContainerRequestContext.java:363)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.preprocess(SynchronousDispatcher.java:156)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:238)
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:249)
    at io.quarkus.resteasy.runtime.ResteasyFilter.doFilter(ResteasyFilter.java:30)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:63)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:65)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:270)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:116)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:113)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.quarkus.undertow.runtime.UndertowDeploymentRecorder$9$1$1.call(UndertowDeploymentRecorder.java:476)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:250)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:59)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:82)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:290)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:669)
    at io.quarkus.runtime.CleanableExecutor$CleaningRunnable.run(CleanableExecutor.java:224)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2011)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1535)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1395)
    at org.jboss.threads.DelegatingRunnable.run(DelegatingRunnable.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads.ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.run(ThreadLocalResettingRunnable.java:29)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
```

Am I missing something?  I found documentation on the Quarkus site for [creating REST clients with multipart](https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client-multipart), but nothing for server-side resources.  Is there something more I need to do to get this working?

Comment: 1) Are you sending an access token? 2) If you aren't sending the first and last names, try to remove the properties (or send them in the request). 3) Try to set the content-type `profileImage=@profile_image.jpg;type=application/octet-stream`. 4) The header `Accepts` should be `Accept`

Comment: Looks like adding the application/octet-stream did it.  Thanks!  Feel free to add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with

```java
@FormParam("profileImage")
@PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
private byte[] profileImage = null;
```

You are advertising that the only content-type you are allowing for this part is `application/octet-stream`. But you are sending an image, and cURL is not setting the content-type of the image to that. I would imagine under the hood it is setting it to `image/jpg`. You could manually set the type (and that will fix *this* request)

```
profileImage=@profile_image.jpg;type=application/octet-stream
```

But personally, I would just remove the `@PartType`. Since the type of the field is already `byte[]`, there will be no problems with conversion. Also, a lot of clients are not able to set individual parts' content-type. Like browser/JS clients will default to setting the content-type for files, just like cURL did.